# Can't display retrieved data from Strapi in the UI, but can see them in the console Using Next.Js

Tags: next.js, graphql, strapi

I am trying to retrieve data from strapi using the NextJs as the front-end. The problem is that I can't display them on the UI, but I can see them in the console.

**I used Graphql for querying the data using this commend:**

```
query {
    menus(filters: {language: {code: {eq: "en"}}}) {
        data {
            attributes {
              Entry {
                title
                link
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

, I got this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "menus": {
      "data": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "Entry": [
              {
                "title": "home",
                "link": "/home.html"
              },
              {
                "title": "classes",
                "link": "./calss.html"
              },
              {
                "title": "events",
                "link": "/events.html"
              },
              {
                "title": "news",
                "link": "/news.html"
              },
              {
                "title": "reosurces",
                "link": "./resources.html"
              },
              {
                "title": "links",
                "link": "./links.html"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**and this is how the UI handled:**

```
const mainMenuAdapter = (menuData) => {
  
  return menuData.map(md => {
    const entry = md['attributes']['Entry']
    console.log('title',  entry)
      return {
        link: entry.link,
        title: entry.title,
      }
    })
  }
```

**I use useContext;**

```
 const { menuData } = useContext(GlobalContext)
  const menus = mainMenuAdapter(menuData)
```

here is how the mapping is handled.

```
   <div className="bg-green-400 relative filosofia_regular bg-grayDark flex-wrap md:flex flex-row items-end md:justify-around p-2 lg:justify-evenly text-center mx-auto w-full">
        {!!menus && menus.map((menu, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <Link href="/">
                <a className="text-gray-100 px-2 text-sm lg:text-2xl xl:text-4xl whitespace-nowrap">
                  {t(menu.title)}
                </a>
              </Link>
              {i < menus.length - 1 && (
                <a className="text-white">|</a>
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

**and here is the console.**

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
link: "/home.html"
title: "home"
__typename: "ComponentEntryComEntry"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {title: 'classes', link: './calss.html', __typename: 'ComponentEntryComEntry'}
2: {title: 'events', link: '/events.html', __typename: 'ComponentEntryComEntry'}
3: {title: 'news', link: '/news.html', __typename: 'ComponentEntryComEntry'}
4: {title: 'reosurces', link: './resources.html', __typename: 'ComponentEntryComEntry'}
5: {title: 'links', link: './links.html', __typename: 'ComponentEntryComEntry'}
length: 6
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you also getting something in your console logging `menus`? (The one you are mapping in your jsx).

Comment: Yes, the result is the one at the end I added to my question.

Comment: Have you tried checking for `menus` array length > 0 instead?

Comment: Nope i didn't. but as you see I used !! in menus map

Comment: Can you try it just for discard purposes and let me know if that works? Since everything else looks good to me.

Comment: Ok, where should i try? in the map?

Comment: Yes, check if `menus.length > 0` and if that's `true`, then map it.

Comment: Here is how i checked but didn't work:

  {menus.map((menu, i) => {
          console.log("getting menu", menu.Entry)
          if (menus.length > 0) {
              return (
            <div key={i}>
              <Link href="/" >
                <a className="text-gray-100 px-2 text-sm lg:text-2xl xl:text-4xl whitespace-nowrap">
                  {t(menu.title)}
                </a>
              </Link>
              {i < menus.length - 1 && (
                <a className="text-white">|</a>
              )}
            </div>
          );
          }
        
        })}

Comment: I meant checking before proceeding to map. Like: `menus.length > 0 && menus.map ...`

Comment: Ok, again didn't work:(

Comment: That's weird... Not errors / warnings on console either?

Comment: Nope nothing...

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre], with the full component's code and including the part where you fetch the data?